# Java Collection and Map

Tags: java, android, list, collections

I am making an android application with Edittext and Listview. In that i want to use java collection to store item and then search the item in that list collection.
My searching method is that: 
At first, we add item to collection.
Then when we type the startup letter of the word in Edittext, that list with get the index of the word that begin with that letter and will setSelection to the listview of that index.
Example: i type a, then it will select to apple, and ..... etc.

I want to know that what kind of collection and Map that can help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should have a look at that
[image: How to choose a java collection]

src : http://chathura-lakmal.blogspot.fr/2010/10/how-to-choose-correct-java-collection.html

Hope that's help

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trie https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706. The example here explains it well. You can specify a prefix and get all the words by traversing the tree

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking at the *first* character typed, and not the subsequent characters of the word, then a simple solution could be an **array** of the alphabet you wish to handle, and have it hold an **ArrayList** of **String**'s. This is extremely simple and light weight, and has good performance as well, see below:

```
    // Create an array with the alphabet from 'a' to 'z' (i.e. English alphabet)
    List<String>[] firstCharLookup = new List[26];

    // Initialize the array to avoid NullPointerException's
    for (int i = 0; i < firstCharLookup.length; i++) {
        firstCharLookup[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // Fill your collections with the strings in the appropriate collections.
    firstCharLookup[0].add("apple");
    firstCharLookup[0].add("active");
    firstCharLookup[0].add("addict");

    firstCharLookup[1].add("bee");
    firstCharLookup[1].add("busy");
    firstCharLookup[1].add("bus");
    // ...
    // Continue with filling dictionary


    // If user types 'a' or 'A' then lowercase the character, then:
    char firstLookup = 'a';
    System.out.println(firstCharLookup[firstLookup - 'a']);
    // We subtract by 'a' so that we get a '0' based index

    // If user types 'b', then:
    char secondLookup = 'b';
    System.out.println(firstCharLookup[secondLookup - 'a']);
```